# Use of Continuity in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus proof

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I wanted to check my understanding of the authors use of continuity in this proof of the FTC: $A'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} = f(t)$

**Context**

Using our classic approach of defining a derivative through limits, where $A(x)$ is an area function i.e. integral, my text book gets:

$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h) \le  \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} \le \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}f(t)$

$f(t) \le  \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} \le f(t)$

$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} = f(t)$

Where we have assumed $h > 0$ and we can use a similar argument for $h < 0$, combining the two gives us the required theorem:

$A'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} = f(t)$

**Question**

The author notes that ***continuity is essential to justify line 1 to line 2***, i.e. that:

$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h) = f(t)$

Is the reason as follows: Only if a function is continuous do we have:

$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$

So letting $x = t + h$

$\lim_{x \to t} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h) = f(t)$ only holds if $f$ is continuous? Where we have used $h \to 0^{+}$ because we assume $h > 0$?

Intuitively could i say something like this: We can't assume that $ x \in [t,t + h]$ goes to t from $t + h$, as $h$ get's smaller and smaller, unless the function is continuous over this interval, and as h could take any possitive value the function must be continuous $\forall x \ge t$...or would it be $ \forall h \ge 0$?

I don't think this 'intuitive' explenation is great, and I realise i'm unclear whether the function needs to be continuous beyond $t$ or beyond $0$ for this to work? Thoughts greatly appreicated thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @emacs drives me nuts

Comment: 1. I don't even see why line 1 is right; is $f$ assumed to be non-increasing at $t$...? 2. "Continuity is essential" is perhaps not what the author meant; instead, "without continuity, line 2 can fail." <> Personally, I think it's preferable to show that if $f$ is continuous at $t$, then $\frac{A(t+h)-A(t)}{h} - f(t) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Do you use the Riemann integral for $A(x)$?

Comment: @Paul Frost,  yes it is using the Reimann integral. But the fact that I didn't think to mention that clearly shows I'm not quite understanding its significance. I'd love your explanation/thoughts on this if you have a minute....for example, if I wasn't using the Reimann integral what would that mean?

Comment: @ Andrew D. Hwang, thanks for your reply: I think what he was saying, and the bit i need help with is that:

Continuity is essential to justify the fact that: $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h) = f(t)$

And i was trying to demonstrate why continuity had to be necessary here by using the idea that: $\lim_{x \to t} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h) = f(t)$

Because a function is only continuous if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$

Have i understood the use of continuity correctly here?

Comment: @PaulFrost i think my comment above get's to the core of my question!

Comment: Which textbook do you use?

Comment: It's actually the University of London Study Guide prepared by the professors A. Ostaszewski and J.M. Ward from LSE. It's probably based off Ostaszewski's book "Advanced Mathematical Methods." 

Below is a link to the study guide:

https://emfss.elearning.london.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/115505/mod_label/intro/MT2176_vle%5B1%5D.pdf

Page 74 footnote 7 is what i am refering too. If you'd be so kind to take a look, that would be amazing!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For definiteness, let's agree that $t_{0}$ and $t$ are real numbers, $f$ is a Riemann-integrable function on some open interval $I$ containing $t_{0}$ and $t$, and
$$
A(t) = \int_{t_{0}}^{t} f(s)\, ds.
$$
Consider the three conditions:

1. $f$ is continuous at $t$.
2. $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}} f(t + h) = f(t)$.
3. $A$ is differentiable at $t$, and $A'(t) = f(t)$.

Loosely, a function $f$ is continuous at $t$ if and only if both one-sided limits at $t$ exist and are equal to $f(t)$. That is, condition 1 implies condition 2; conversely, condition 2 and the analogous condition for a left-hand limit imply condition 1.

Further, condition 1 implies condition 3 (this is part of the FTC), but condition 3 *does not imply* condition 1. A typical counterexample is to let $f(s) = 1$ if $s = 1/n$ for some non-zero integer $n$, and $f(s) = 0$ otherwise. The integral $A$ is identically $0$ (!), hence differentiable, and $A'(0) = 0 = f(0)$ (condition 3 holds) but the function $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ (condition 1 fails). In this sense, it would be inaccurate to say "continuity of $f$ at $t$ is essential to deduce that $A'(t) = f(t)$." (That's not your authors' claim; just saying.)

---

Next let's examine "line 1" in the argument: If $t + h \in I$, then
$$
\frac{A(t+h) - A(t)}{h}
= \frac{1}{h}\biggr[\int_{t_{0}}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds - \int_{t_{0}}^{t} f(s)\, ds\biggr]
= \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds.
$$
In general, this expression is neither bounded below by $f(t + h)$ nor bounded above by $f(t)$. In this sense, I don't understand where
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} f(t + h)
\leq \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{A(t + h) - A(t)}{h}
\leq \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}f(t)
$$
comes from. (If $f$ is continuous at $t$, or even continuous from the right at $t$, the preceding inequality is *true*, but to deduce it we'd effectively need the theorem we're attempting to prove.)

Be that as it may, if the preceding inequality is established, then the limits do evaluate as in line 2 because condition 1 implies condition 2. But based on the context given, it's difficult to evaluate the claim **continuity is essential to justify line 1 to line 2**: If $f$ is not continuous at $t$, the leftmost limit in line 1 may or may not exist, separately from whether the leftmost limit is equal to $f(t)$. But this does not appear to be the pedagogical point being made.

---

Finally, though this was not asked, here's how I'd prove the FTC, avoiding the points in question here: If $t + h \in I$, then
\begin{align*}
  \biggl|\frac{A(t + h) - A(t)}{h} - f(t)\biggr|
  &= \biggl|\frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds - f(t)\biggr|
  && \text{preceding calculation} \\
  &= \biggl|\frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds - \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} f(t)\, ds\biggr|
  && \text{$f(t)$ is constant} \\
  &= \biggl|\frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} [f(s) - f(t)]\, ds\biggr|
  && \text{linearity of the integral} \\
  &\leq \biggl|\frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t+h} |f(s) - f(t)|\, ds\biggr|
  && \text{triangle inequality for integrals} \\
  &\leq \sup_{|s - t| \leq |h|} |f(s) - f(t)|
  && \text{monotonicity of the integral.}
\end{align*}
Because $f$ is continuous at $t$, the right-hand side can be made as small as we like by taking $|h|$ sufficiently small. By definition,
$$
A'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{A(t + h) - A(t)}{h} = f(t).
$$

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort into this! Will review after work today!

Comment: Hi Andrew I was just revising this. Your section on the three conditions. You state that continuity implies differentiability, but differentiability does not imply continuity. Could you elaborate on this, as I understand it is the exact opposite of standard practice/assumptions. Normally we say differentiability implies continuity but not the other way around right?

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem, taken from the seventh chapter of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (third edition) shows that, in order for the indefinite integral to be differentiable at every point and its derivative equal the integrated function, it is  *not essential* that the integrated function is continuous. So you can take a differentiable function whose derivative is integrable but has discontinuities (by Darboux's theorem, necessarily discontinuities of the second kind, i.e. at least one of the one-sided limits doesn't exist).

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y90zF.png)

Comment: HI @uniquesolution, thanks for your reply. That's interesting, and I haven't seen it before, so thanks for sharing. I suppose my question isn't about the necessity of continuity in proving the FTC generally. But with regards to this specific proof, I wanted to check how continuity was being used, and whether my understanding was correct? What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Rudin's theorem does not address the question. It uses the Lebesgue integral, but that is not the point. It starts with a differentiable function $A$ and says that **if $A'$ is Lebesgue integrable**, then $A(x) - A(a) = \int_a^x A'(t)dt$. In the question one starts with an integrable $f$ and then shows that $A(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable at $x$ with $A'(x) = f(x)$ provided $f$ is continuous at $x$. See Rudin's Theorem 7.11 and "7.6 Lebesgue points".

Comment: @PaulFrost - Since Rimeann integrable implies Lebesgue integrable, the theorem I quoted proves that continuity is not essential in **Riemann's integral**

Comment: @uniquesolution What is needed is not Theorem 7.21, but Theorem 7.11.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion here guys: For reference, this is what I am referring to exactly: 

University of London Study Guide prepared by the professors A. Ostaszewski and J.M. Ward from LSE. https://emfss.elearning.london.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/115505/mod_label/intro/MT2176_vle%5B1%5D.pdf
Page 74 footnote 7 is what I am referring to. If you get a chance to take a look, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens with a discontinuous function. Consider, for example,

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&x=a,\\
0,&x\neq a,
\end{cases}$$

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then

$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=\lim_{h\to0}0=0,$$

but

$$f(a)=1,$$

and so

$$\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)\neq f(a).$$

If we have a continuous function then your reasoning seems to work. Do you see now why continuity is required?

Comment: Thanks for this @Lorago, i'm slightly confused by your notation. Is what you wrote for the function the same as saying:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\ f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,&x=a,\\ 0,&x\neq a, \end{cases}$

Comment: Yes it is @CormJack